# How to access updated records from image table through DB Link

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I create public database link in database 11g for access images table from another database 11g server. I found custom function for select BLOB tables. When I insert new records in Image Tables and try to select image table through database link and custom function then retrive only old records.

**Custom Function for BLOB Columns:**

```
create or replace function GETBLOBVIADBLINK
( dblnk in varchar2
,tbl  in varchar2
,col  in varchar2)
return blob
 is
retval blob;
tmpraw raw(2000);  
tmplen number;
tmpchk number;
chksize number;
 begin
--preset vars
chksize:=2000;
dbms_lob.createtemporary (retval,true);
execute immediate 'select dbms_lob.getlength@'||dblnk||' ('||col||') from '||tbl||'@'||dblnk||'' into tmplen;

-- precalc  
tmpchk:=floor(tmplen/chksize);

-- applicate frist chunks  
for i in 0 .. tmpchk-1
loop  
execute immediate 'select dbms_lob.substr@'||dblnk||'('||col||','||chksize||','||((i*chksize)+1)||') from '||tbl||'@'||dblnk||'' into tmpraw;
dbms_lob.append(retval,tmpraw);
end loop;

-- applicate last entry
if (tmplen-(tmpchk*chksize)) > 0 then
execute immediate 'select dbms_lob.substr@'||dblnk||'('||col||','||(tmplen-(tmpchk*chksize))||','||((tmpchk*chksize)+1)||') from '||tbl||'@'||dblnk||'' into tmpraw;
dbms_lob.append(retval,tmpraw);
end if;
return retval;
end;
```

**Select Command:**

```
SELECT m.column
,getblobviadblink('dblink','table_name','column_name') image
FROM  table_name@dblink m;
```

How to access latest and updated records through database link?

Thanks

Comment: When you said ** When I insert new records in Image Tables**, have you committed the transaction using `COMMIT;`?

Comment: @Tejash Yes Commit after insert new rocord in image table